# Python-How to display the for loop only once?

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate column of alphabet in 'new.xlsx', and if the alphabet exists in 'original.xlsx', then copy the data and paste into new.xlsx.
The code following is what I have done.

```
import openpyxl

dappend = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/User/Desktop/original.xlsx', data_only=True)
dp1 = dappend.active
consider = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/User/Desktop/new.xlsx', data_only=True)
cd1 = consider.active

li2 = []
for c in range(2,cd1.max_row+1):
    name = cd1.cell(row=c,column=4).value
    for d in range(2,dp1.max_row+1):
        if cd1.cell(row=c,column=4).value == dp1.cell(row=d,column=4).value:
            li2=[dp1.cell(row=d,column=4).value,dp1.cell(row=d,column=5).value,dp1.cell(row=d,column=6).value,dp1.cell(row=d,column=7).value]
            print(li2)
            d = d + 1
        else:
            continue
    c = c + 1
```

My output is:

```
['A', None, 'Jonathan', None]
['A', '', 'Jonathan', '']
['B', None, 'Cassandra', None]
['B', None, 'Rose', None]
['B', 'Tyler', None, None]
['B', '', 'Cassandra', '']
['B', '', 'Rose', '']
['B', 'Tyler', '', '']
['C', 'Sam', None, None]
['C', 'Sam', '', '']
['D', 'Jeremy', None, None]
['D', 'Jeremy', '', '']
```

but I expected the output to be like...

```
['A', '', 'Jonathan', '']
['B', '', 'Cassandra', '']
['B', '', 'Rose', '']
['B', 'Tyler', '', '']
['C', 'Sam', '', '']
['D', 'Jeremy', '', '']
```

Please help...

Comment: For somebody to be able to reproduce your problem (which is an essential step in crafting an answer), they need to be able to run your code. Can you provide a link to the input file so that potential answerers can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I apologize for that. Yes I will provide the link after. I couldn't provide the link this time since the data is all Korean and I translated when I post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a comment: the lines c = c+1 and d = d+1 do nothing since in the beggining of the loop they get redefined as the next item in your list: range(2,5) = (2,3,4)

Now to your solution:
I would suggest you add an if before the print command

```
if None in li2 :
   # do nothing
else:
   print(li2)
```